# I need a USB keyboard, mouse and wi-fi adapter to work on my RPI *under 200mA*

Tags: power, keyboard, mouse

I am the co-founder of http://communitykit.org/.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a good combination of a wired keyboard, mouse and wireless adapter for the Raspberry Pi.  The trick is they all can't consume more than 200mA because the rest of the power is used for the hard drive / other hardware.

Does anyone have any advise or should I just go fishing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the type of question where fully explaining what you are trying to accomplish and explaining your complete setup (is the HDD drive powered from the PI? are you using a powered hub?) will help in generating answers.

Comment: In my tests, I gotta say, you'll be happy if you can get a the HDD working at all. Just buy some cheap USB Hub. As for the receiver, I have A k800 keyboard and a Performance MX mouse, both by Logitech, they are working great so far. (obviously is not cheap, tho)

Comment: A long shot would be using one of those wireless keyboard-mouse combo with one nano receiver which may go as low as 50mA. You can also find a cheap nano wifi adapter which will work in the range of 100-110mA. I don't think you can use a USB Hub without external power for what you require + the HDD

Comment: Regarding WiFi: Low power or good coverage, choose one. It directly needs to convert power to electromagnetic (radio) waves to reach the accesspoint at reasonable distance or through obstacles.

Answer (score 3):

I have a nano size wifi adapter and an el cheapo wireless keyboard/mouse combo, they are useable together, but I would not recommend it.  The keyboard often repeats, which I believe is related to the "underpowered" issue.

However, you mention a hard drive.  The pi only has two USB ports, so it's physically impossible to plug in a drive, a keyboard, and a wifi dongle.  If you are considering an adapter/unpowered hub to increase the number of ports: **don't bother**.  As is, *the pi does not come close to meeting the USB 2.0 power standard* (500 mA per port); I don't see anyone claiming you can expect more than **150 mA TOTAL**.  If you have a good reason to believe you can plug in a drive and have 200 mA left over, please share it.

Otherwise, if you want to do this you will need to use a powered hub.  If you are intending to use this rig as part of your education campaign, I recommend against the pi.  While it was designed for educational purposes, the educational purposes it was designed for involve *educating people about computers and electronics*, and not *serving as a general purpose computer*.  By the time you include a display, SD card, keyboard, wifi, a drive, and the powered hub (and/or power supply), you are up into three figures -- for that money you would be better served with a cheap Android tablet or netbook, which are intended for general purpose use.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a dual PS/2 to USB adapter for keyboard and mouse?  I'm not sure about the power draw, but that might help you on USB port usage without sacrificing the wires.